# Expanding the CSS product section

Tags: css

I'm trying to use the justify-content: space-between function and my e-shop product page to stretch each product if the title is single-line, like here:

https://stankomat.cz

I tried to use this function on a whole block of one product and the function will apply between the image and the text, and I need it to apply between the description and the price line and the button.

I understand where this problem arises, but I absolutely do not understand how to solve this. I tried writing this code but it doesn't perform the function.

```
.p-bottom {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
height: 100%;
}
```

If I apply the same style to the whole frame, it works great, but in the spot below the product photo, which I don't want.

Is there a solution that can solve this? I've spent a really long time on this and can't find any result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By grouping the top half of the product (image, title, description), and the bottom half (price and purchase button) into two containers (`.container-top` and `.container-bottom` in my example), you are able to set your parent div (`.product`) to use flex's space-between layout to achieve what you're trying to get.

```css
.product {
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container-top {
  background-color: #aaffaa;
}

.container-bottom {
  background-color: #aaaaff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div style=display:flex;flex-direction:row;gap:8px;>
  <div class=product>
    <div class=container-top>
      <h2>Product Name</h2>
      <span>Lorum ipsum dolor</span>
    </div>
    <div class=container-bottom>
      <span>$100</span>
      <button>Purchase</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=product>
    <div class=container-top>
      <h2>Product Name That is Long and Spills Across Multiple Lines</h2>
      <span>Lorum ipsum dolor</span>
    </div>
    <div class=container-bottom>
      <span>$100</span>
      <button>Purchase</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=product>
    <div class=container-top>
      <h2>Medium Product Name</h2>
      <span>Lorum ipsum dolor</span>
    </div>
    <div class=container-bottom>
      <span>$100</span>
      <button>Purchase</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```